# Execute query depending of Oracle version

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have to execute a sql on several oracle server/instance.
 If the oracle version is 12g then the  table i want to query is 'foo'. If the oracle version is 11g, then the table will be 'bar'

i tried something  that, but I don't know much about cursor

```
    CURSOR C1
    IS

             SELECT version FROM V$INSTANCE


    MY_VERSION VARCHAR2 ( 500 );
BEGIN
    OPEN C1;

    FETCH C1
    INTO
           MY_QUERY;

    CLOSE C1;

    IF MY_QUERY like '%12.%
    THEN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select * from foo';
ELSE IF MY_QUERY like '%11.%'

        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select * from bar';
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Will both tables exist in each version?  If so, frjtorres' answer should work.  If the tables don't even exist, then you may need to use conditional compilation.

Comment: well, both tables may exist but not on purpose; so i can't just do ```desc foo``` and execute query based on it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is actually a very bad plan. If the versions are different just write a different procedure specific to each version, if they're the same then name the tables the same. Proceeding with this plan is likely to be a maintenance nightmare and will clearly be so in problem analysis and resolution later. But you can do this with Conditional Compilation. Example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE foo_or_bar  AS

    $IF DBMS_DB_VERSION.VER_LE_11 $THEN
    type myfoobar_t is table of bar%rowtype;
    $ELSE
    type myfoobar_t in table of foo%rowtype;
    $END

    myfoobar myfoobar_t;
BEGIN
    $IF DBMS_DB_VERSION.VER_LE_11 $THEN
    select * 
      bulk collect 
      into myfoobar
      from bar; 
    $ELSE
    select * 
      bulk collect 
      into myfoobar
      from foo;     
    $END
   ... 
end foo_or_bar;
```

Answer (score 2):

the next anonymous subprogram can help you to solve your question.

```
declare
     type v_foo is table of foo%rowtype index by pls_integer;
     t_foo v_foo;

     type v_bar is table of bar%rowtype index by pls_integer;
     t_bar v_bar;
begin
    if dbms_db_version.version = 12 then
        execute immediate 'select * from foo' bulk collect into t_foo;
    elsif dbms_db_version.version = 11 then
        execute immediate 'select * from bar' bulk collect into t_bar;
    end if;
end;
```

Comment: Unlike the Conditional Compilation solution this approach requires FOO and BAR to exist in both database versions, Perhaps that is the case, the question is unclear on the matter. But if it's not the case the target variables need to be defined using RECORD types rather than `%rowtype`,

Comment: @APC FOO and BAR may not exist in all the database. Could you provide an exemple with Record Types?

Answer (score 0):

Another approach,

```
DECLARE
    v_SQL VARCHAR2(2000);
    v_instance VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
    SELECT name INTO v_instance FROM V$database;
    IF (NVL(v_instance, 'EE12C') = 'EE12C') THEN
        -- 12C related script goes here
        v_SQL := '';
    END IF;    
    IF (NVL(v_instance, 'EE19C') = 'EE19C') THEN 
        -- 19C related script goes here
        v_SQL := '';
    END IF;        
END;
/
```

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score -1):

The only correct way to solve this issue is to place some compiler directives in the source code, so it can be ported to newer versions as well.
This is done by using (example for code that's not supported by Oracle versions before or equal 11)

$IF DBMS_DB_VERSION.VER_LE_11 $THEN
*calls to procedures that are supported in Oracle versions before or equal 11*
$ELSE
*calls to procedures supported from Oracle version 12 and up*
$END

For example, from Oracle 18 **dbms_lock.sleep** is replaced by **dbms_session.sleep**. So if you use dbms_lock.sleep, you need to replace it by dbms_session.sleep when on version 18 or higher. By doing so, the code won't no longer run on previous versions, unless you use the compiler directive and implement both methods, one for versions before and one for the versions after.

Read more here: [Oracle DBMS_DB_VERSION](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_DB_VERSION.html)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: ok, no idea how to make this more clear, sorry.

Comment: After editing your answer I can't see why I marked your question as unclear. Anyway, your answer isn't adding anything new to a question asked 3 years ago and is similar to the answer provided by @user11846888 on July 28, 2019, so if I were reviewing your answer now I would marked it as duplicated.

Comment: In all fairness, I was triggered to reply to user11846888. This user's approach is wrong as one can't compile on systems which don't have the object, therefore the ONLY solution would be to use compiler_directives. User Belayer described it correctly, in his earlier reply, so I just wanted to make sure that other readers are aware that user11846888's is unusable.